# What is /tmp/t$$?

Tags: bash, temporary-files, tmp

The title, basically.
I've seen it used in some progs, like here to do something if the output of a command contains some text:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp=/tmp/t$$
mycommand > $tmp 
if grep -q 'Mytext' $tmp
then
   action
fi

rm -f $tmp
exit 0
```

I find it very usefull, and started using it, but I don't like using thing I don't really understand.
Two things are unclear for me here:

1. what the `tmp=/tmp/t$$` exactly does (what is that `t$$` thing?? The double dollar really confuse me)
2. How does the `$tmp` works? I mean, I get that we can put the output of the command in `$tmp` just as if we were writing it to a file (and find it better with `$tmp`, without creating temporary files), but when we delete it with `rm $tmp`, what exactly happens? Is there a temporary file named `t$$`in `/tmp` that got deleted?

I couldn't find an answer online and I really would like to understand it.

Comment: _What is `$$`_?  See: `PAGER='less +/^\ *bashpid' man bash`

Comment: _what is $tmp?_ It is the value of tmp. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: Add the `set -xv` at the top of your script, right after the shebang, before executing it. Should give you some info about it.

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/learn-difference-between-and-bashpid-in-bash/

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62231/bashpid-and-differ-in-some-cases

Comment: @matt I know what a $$ means in general in shell, although I don't use it so it's not perfectly clear to me. But I don't understand it in this particular case, with `/tmp/t$$`. I also understand what `$tmp` is, as said, but with they way tmp is defined here I'm unsure about the implications. 
Also if you comment only to be mean and judgemental, please just don't. I've spent nearly an hour to search for an explanation, and it seemed like something basic that people here could easily answer, not worth another hour of useless online search. Sorry if you're not happy with the question.

Comment: Okay then. Think of this as a UUID so that you can create a temp file unique to this running script. If we are 123 this will be _t123_ in _tmp_. And the variable `tmp` refers to it, so `$tmp` _is_ it. Does that help?

Comment: @Ablia, one can always check what is the value of a variable, regardless of the value, either by `echo "$variable"` or `declare -p variable` , note that the latter does not have a dollar sign before the `variable` string. In your particular case, `declare -p tmp` add it just after the assignment, or Like what i've posted before, add `set -xv`

Comment: @Ablia, this might help/shed some light on your query. [How can I create a temp file in a secure manner](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/062)

Comment: I think you should use `mktemp` or `mktemp -d` instead of relying on `$$` (the shell’s PID) as a unique (enough) identifier. Also, a good pattern may be: `declare -r tmp="$(mktemp)"; trap 'rm "$tmp";' EXIT;`, which will clean up the file (almost) no matter which way the script exits; this is especially important when running with `set -e` (which I’d generally recommend).

Comment: @Jetchisel didn't know that `set -xv` command, it's really usefull! gonna use it more in the future, thanks!
@matt actually yes, thank you. Didn't realize it would be simply interpreted as part of the filename, thought it might be doing something else that I didn't know about. Makes much more sense know. However I don't see how it can be "unique" to this script: If I run the script more than once, or if I run another script using that, in the same shell, then the file will have the same name, right? But since it's a temp file that get deleted each time I guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks to all of your comments, I get it now :) 
Weird how it seems basic and obvious now, bit ashamed that I wasn't able to understand it by myself, but sometimes the simplest stuff is really obscure to me.

Comment: In you case `if command | grep -q 'MyTest'; then action; fi` would be enough, not temp file to create or delete

Comment: *"... it seemed like something basic that people here could easily answer, not worth another hour of useless online search"* - Advice:  If your default approach to solving problems like this is to Google it and trawl through the hits ... I think you are doing it wrong.  A better way is to go to the documentation (e.g. `man bash`) read what it says about `$$` and `$name`, and apply the knowledge to the problem at hand.  (A programmer needs to be able to read code.  Using the docs as a "dictionary" if necessary.)  For debugging shell scripts, check out what `set -x` and `set -v` do ...

Comment: Maybe ... what you are missing that the process id returned by `$$` will be different each time you run the script.  Because each time the script is running in a different process.  (Modulo that the PID sequence wraps around, and is reset on reboot.  So it is not strictly unique.  So there is a small chance of collisions on temp filenames created using `$$`.  Usually "meh".)

Answer (score 0):

The double-dollar is the process-id of the current shell.

The script above sets the variable "tmp" to the "/tmp/t123456" *(where 123456 is the process id of the current running script).*

I think the "t" is just a string the author chose to use.

Another approach could be to do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
temp_file=/tmp/t$RANDOM
mycommand > $temp_file 

...

rm -f $temp_file
exit 0
```

-Scott